# Taylor series of $\sin(x^2)$

Tags: integration, taylor-expansion

I am stuck on a problem for my calc 2 course. We are being asked to use Taylor series centered around x=0 (Maclaurin series) to approximate $\sin(x^2)$ and we are being asked to calculate the first five (non-zero) terms in the series and then integrate using our approximation. The issue is there are a lot of zero terms therefore by the time I reach my third term (that has a value) I am up to the tenth derivative. We never go this high and I think I must be missing something (?). Sorry if this question is confusing I'm fairly new to this sort of calculus and I couldn't find any examples using this function.

Comment: If the Maclaurin series of $\sin(z)$ looks like $z-z^3/6+z^5/120-\cdots,$ what does the Maclaurin series of $\sin(x^2)$ look like?

Comment: It would be that but squared?

Comment: Careful: what do you mean by 'that'?

Comment: Sorry not exactly "that" but the first five terms of the Maclaurin series of sin(x) and then I would square them?

Comment: Are you computing the Maclaurin series by differentiating $\cos(x^2)$ lots of times?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  You want $\sin(x^2)$, not $(\sin(x))^2$

Comment: Feng Qi, Da-Wei Niu, Dongkyu Lim, and Yong-Hong Yao, Special values of the Bell polynomials of the second kind for some sequences and functions, Journal of Mathematical Analysis and Applications, vol. 491 (2020), no. 2, Paper No. 124382, 31 pages; available online at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jmaa.2020.124382.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of computing the derivatives of $\sin(x^2)$ to find it's Maclaurin series, it would be easier if we were to substitute $x^2$ into $x$ in the Maclaurin series of $\sin(x)$. We know that
$$\sin(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^5}{120}\cdots$$
Therefore, we substitute $x^2$ into each $x$ in the equation and we get
$$\sin(x^2)=x^2-\frac{({x^2})^3}{6}+\frac{({x^2})^5}{120}\cdots=x^2-\frac{x^6}{6}+\frac{x^{10}}{120}\cdots$$
Can you try to deduce the remaining 2 terms according to this?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much this helps a lot

Comment: Strictly speaking, I do not think this is sufficient. The sequence you ultimately generate is, indeed, the Maclaurin series of the function $\sin \circ (\cdot)^2$, but this is *not* a satisfactory proof of the claim.